# Playwright/Chromium - how to retry failed requests?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, playwright

I'm writing a bot using Typescript and Playwright. It's connecting to the Internet over SSH tunnel -> LTE modem. Occasionally some requests to JS scripts would fail (presumably because of laggy proxy), and I want to retry them. How do I do this?

I've tried to use the `page.route` method, but it doesn't even open Google properly:

```
import {chromium, Route} from "playwright";

const browser = await chromium.launch({
    headless: false
});

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.route('**/*', async (route: Route) => {
    const response = await page.request.fetch(route.request());
    await route.fulfill({response});
});

await page.goto('https://google.com');

await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 100000));
await browser.close();
```